# how to validate password in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Here is my html code for a signup page but i am not able to validate the password field. what happens here is whenever i enter a password and click on confirm password it displays the error message without even allowing me to enter my password again.. please help me fix this! thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="signup">

            <form action="insert.php" method="POST" onclick="return validation();">
                  <div id="eresult" style="color: red;"></div>
        <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter New Username" required id="name">
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="Email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required id="email">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required id="pass">
            <p>Confirm Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="confpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" required id="confpass">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function validation(){
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var confpassword = document.getElementById('confpass').value;

            if(password == confpassword){
                  return true;

            }
            else{
                  alert("Password does not match!!");

                  return false;
            }
      }

      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use the onsubmit action in form instead of the onclick. Since you are using onclick currently, the validation code triggers on click anywhere on the form - and returns false when the password is changed and you move to the confirm password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that in your form html element, you are calling onclick event that executes when you click on any html element, so pass value and confpass value are undefined till you change one of those, that's why you see the alert.
The solution : use onsubmit event.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refresh the HTML from server or cache with `location.reload(true)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="signup">

            <form action="insert.php" method="POST" onclick="return validation();">
                  <div id="eresult" style="color: red;"></div>
        <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter New Username" required id="name">
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="Email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required id="email">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required id="pass">
            <p>Confirm Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="confpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" required id="confpass">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function validation(){
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var confpassword = document.getElementById('confpass').value;

            if(password == confpassword){
                  return true;

            }
            else{
                  alert("Password does not match!!");
                 location.reload(true)
                  return false;
            }
      }

      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also this is strictly JS related question, I would also change your js to it's own main file and not inline (my personal opinion)